# Python File Keeps Running Previous Output

Tags: python, file-handling

I am writing an interpreter that can understand English commands, for example, 'say Hello World.' The Python code reads input from stdin. I have no problem with that. Then it translates it into Python code and appends it to a file. Again, no problem. Then I have a function that runs the code in the file. The function goes like this:

```
def run(runfile):
   with open(runfile,"r") as rnf:
     exec(rnf.read())
```

Then I just write:

```
run("file.py")
```

I then run the code in the file and simulate the output.
Then I open the file as if to write to it and then close it at the end of the program (on the last line) to delete the file's contents like this:

```
open("file.py", "w").close()
```

The problem is that when I type in English commands and run the file, it runs properly. Then I type in a different English command, and it runs the output from the *previous* execution. Then I run it again and it works properly. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? (Feel free to ask questions about my code)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. could you clarify this sentence? "The problem is that when I type in English commands and run the file, it runs properly."

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are not appending each command passed to your file. In that case (if you are appending from the start), it will always start executing from the previous saves and continue on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone but I fixed the problem by compiling it all into a string and then using `exec()` on it.